# Columnwise concatenation of two CSV files with same number of rows

Tags: python, csv

I want to concatenate two CSV files to merge them into a single CSV file. The columns of the first CSV file should come after all the columns of second CSV file. I want some code in Python. Can you help me in doing this?

This is my try:

```
 from itertools import izip
 import csv 

 with open('output.csv','rb') as f1, open('mnist_images.csv','rb') as f2, open('outputFinal.csv','wb') as w:
     writer = csv.writer(w) for r1,r2 in izip(f1,f2):
         writer.writerow(r1+r2)
```

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: I have tried the following code snippet to get it done:                                                                               from itertools import izip
import csv
with open('output.csv','rb') as f1, open('mnist_images.csv','rb') as f2, open('outputFinal.csv','wb') as w:
    writer = csv.writer(w)
    for r1,r2 in izip(f1,f2):
        writer.writerow(r1+r2)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
fout = open("first.csv","a")
for line in open("second.csv"):  
    fout.write(line)
# not really needed
fout.close()
```

Comment: please upvote my question so that i can get sufficient repuation points to upvote yours. Due to low number of reputations, I am unable to upvote your answer.

Answer (score 2):

One of the most powerful tools for this task is [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/). You can create data-frames, then concatenate them.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv')

df3 = pd.concat([df2, df1], axis=1)
df3.to_csv('file3.csv', index=False)
```

Illustration of data:

```
file1.csv                       file2.csv
      a,b,c,d                   e,f,g,h
      10,10,10,10               110,110,110,110
      20,20,20,20               220,220,220,220
      30,30,30,30               330,330,330,330
file3.csv
      e,f,g,h,a,b,c,d
      110,110,110,110,10,10,10,10
      220,220,220,220,20,20,20,20
      330,330,330,330,30,30,30,30
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import glob
import pandas as pd


df = pd.concat(list(map(pd.read_csv, glob.glob("./*.csv"))), axis=1)
df.to_csv('file_merged.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: please upvote my question so that i can get sufficient repuation points to upvote yours. Due to low number of reputations, I am unable to upvote your answer.